# Have Right implication sign all the way to the left inside align environment

Tags: math-mode

I want to add \Rightarrow into my align environment (or something similar) all the way to the left of a specific line. However whenever I try to do this I either get that the arrow sticks with the line or it pushes the rest of the line all the way to the right instead of the preferred behaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y &= mx+c \\
\leftalign{\Rightarrow} \\
y - c &= mx \\
\leftalign{\Rightarrow}\\
&\text{blah...blah...blah...}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your swift comment, I've added a MWE for you to look at, as you can see the \Rightarrow symbol remains in the middle with the rest of the stuff I want to keep centered, I would really like it to be all the way or at least partially to the left. Thanks!

Comment: I think it'll look strange to the far left. But have a look at the `\ArrowBetweenLines` macro in `mathtools`

Comment: Thanks daleif, that looks useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd normally just switch to `alignat*` and then use `\ArrowBetweenLines` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&&y &= mx+c \\
\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]
&&y - c &= mx \\
\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]
&&&\text{blah...blah...blah...}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.